# first try bevel tool

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bevel

I saw some people making 3d text very cool,
they told me about the bevel tool, but when I tried it nothing happened
[image: expectation]

here is my expectation,(photoshop)

when i tried in blender nothing happened am i wrong for use that tools??  [image]

ive tried but i just get the minor result[image]

i found on net, i must fixed the topology first and still noting happend[image]

here is the file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iW4hs0fi3k-wQAXKbYUeETBGHZefci9X/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any automatic way to do it, but what you can do is:

- Convert to mesh, <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* enough to delete all overlapping vertices:

[image]

- Use your image as model and the knife as tool to cut all the inner lines:

[image]

- Pull these lines to get the 3D relief, shade smooth and auto-smooth (the topology here probably needs to be improved, particularly if you add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier):

[image]

Comment: thank you very much sir!!. really appreciate :D

Comment: you're welcome, as I said the topology was quickly made here, just for demonstration

Comment: maybe can share files XD

Comment: sure: https://pasteall.org/blend/469b5daddd224c8fbed99c833c2ce96c